# Import LimeSurvey DB from data only

Tags: mysql, limesurvey

I backed up my Limesurvey data. Later my database got hosed by a virus.  Okay, good thing I have a backup! Except... When I backed up, I apparently neglected to "Save CREATE Schema", so my backup is data only.

So I figured I could set up a new install, remove the new data, and restore my data.

OOPS! It creates tables when you actually create a survey. Another table when you turn on tokens. Okay, I'll do those things too.  Change the new table names to match the ones in my data, aaaaaannnd...

No dice.  Mismatch in number of table fields.  At this point I'm at a loss -- does it alter the actual table field count during usage???

At any rate, I'm stuck. I'm just trying to get the danged survey back.  I have the data, but can't manage to create a table structure that matches the data structure.  Any suggestion as to how I might accomplish this?

Comment: Silly question but... The new installation is the same varsion as the old one, right?

    Also, when activating, you can decide some stuff. Have you activated using the same settings?

    At last, probably, the new survey has different id and question ids, so, not sure the field names will match,

Comment: I would be kind of shocked if the actual field *names* changed based on the data.  That's data, not structure. But I guess I've seen weirder things in software.